# How to catch not translated keys when using @ ngx-translate

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to edit the pipe of the library @ ngx-translate / core, to know what words are not being translated and save them to send them in a separate service

```js
export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
    handle (params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
        if (params.translateService.currentLang === params.translateService.defaultLang) {
            return 'not translate';
        }
    }
  }

@NgModule ({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot (appRoutes),
        SharedModule,
        FuseMainModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot ({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            missingTranslationHandler: {provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler}
        }),
```

This at the moment, has caused that in the words without translations, replace them with the word 'not translate', and what I need is to capture the word that can not be translated.

I tried to modify the file translate.pipe.d.ts, but I could not know how to get that value. really very grateful to the one who can help me

Comment: Welcome. Maybe you can try to use `MissingTranslationHandler`. However your question, the way it is formulated, is not cool. Visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you, is that I need to know what is the text that can not be translated

Comment: Yup, I got what your question is about. Still, it is common around here to show what you have tried, show some effort, show some code and error messages if any.. [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, here it is. Use `MissingTranslationHandler` as stated in comments.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
    this.nts.notTranslated(params.key);
    return '[MISSING]' + params.key;
  }

  constructor(private nts: NotTranslatedService) {}
}
```

Initialize `TranslateModule` with:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot ({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        },
        missingTranslationHandler: {
            provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
            useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler,
            deps: [NotTranslatedService]
        }
    })
```

...and the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotTranslatedService {
  ...
  notTranslated(key: string) {
     console.log('Not translated', key);
     // do whatever you want...
  }
}
```

Comment: Friend very grateful to you, this served me a lot. thank you very much for your help

Comment: You don't need an extra service I think. You can do the log inside the handler and the extra deps: 

  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
    console.error('Missing translation key:', params.key);
    return '[MISSING]' + params.key;
  }

Comment: @RonJonk of course, that depends on what you want to do. Chances are you want to push that to server and in the service you can inject `HttpClient` for example etc.